# Read with MXRecordIO from bytes object

Tags: python-3.x, mxnet, bytesio

Is there a way that I can use `mx.recordio.MXRecordIO` to read from a bytes object rather than a file object?

For example I'm currently doing:

```
import mxnet as mx

results_file = 'results.rec'
with open(results_file, 'wb') as f:
    f.write(results)

recordio = mx.recordio.MXRecordIO(results_file, 'r')
temp = recordio.read()
```

But if possible I'd rather not have to write to file as an intermediate step. I've tried using BytesIO, but can't seem to get it to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently they is no way of achieving this sorry. This is non-trivial because the RecordIO reading/parsing is done in C++ and you can't simply forward the stream to the C++ API.